# How to use find_if to find a matching object of a class? (Or any other way to achieve the result)

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, find, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to traverse through a vector of "Stimulus" class objects. And if the properties of the object match the criteria, I want that Stimulus object returned.

```
std::vector<Stimulus> BS_stimulus_list;

bool StimulusCollection::isNextPoint(Stimulus it){
if(it.GetPointDeg()=="(Some json value)" & it.GetEye()==currentEye){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}

void StimulusCollection::NextBSStimulus(char e){
currentEye = e;
if (currentEye=='L'){
    vector<Stimulus>::iterator idx = find_if(BS_stimulus_list.begin(), BS_stimulus_list.end(),isNextPoint);
}
```

The code above gives me a compile error : must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in.....
What am I doing wrong? Or what should I do differently to avoid this altogether?

Comment: Is `isNextPoint` a static or non static function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the instance, either by using a lambda (see below) or `std::bind`

```
void StimulusCollection::NextBSStimulus(char e) {
    currentEye = e;
    if (currentEye=='L'){
        vector<Stimulus>::iterator idx = find_if(
            BS_stimulus_list.begin(), 
            BS_stimulus_list.end(),
            [this](const auto& stimulus) { return isNextPoint(stimulus); });
    }
}
```

(for C++14, change `const auto&` to `const Stimulus&` for older versions)

Comment: Thanks, this works with a little modification.
        [this](const auto& stimulus) { return isNextPoint(stimulus); });
is changed to 
        [this](const Stimulus& stimulus) { return isNextPoint(stimulus); });

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `isNextPoint` is marked `static`, you need to explicitly qualify it:

```
find_if(BS_stimulus_list.begin(), 
        BS_stimulus_list.end(), 
        StimulusCollection::isNextPoint)
```

If it's not `static` you can use a *lambda expression* in order to bind the invocation of `isNextPoint` to a particular instance of `StimulusCollection`.